# Error in one page shinnyapp.io application

Tags: r, shinyapps

I am trying to deploy a single `*.Rmd` file to shinnyapps.io and get the following error in the interface:

> ```
> An error has occurred The application failed to start (exited with code 1).
>
> Error in enforcePackage(name, curVersion) :    The rmarkdown package was not found in the library. Calls: local ... eval -> eval ->
> eval -> <Anonymous> -> enforcePackage Execution halted
> ```

Application logs look like this:

> ```
> 2019-03-09T21:34:42.167089+00:00 shinyapps[778397]: Server version:
> 1.7.0-11 2019-03-09T21:34:42.167117+00:00 shinyapps[778397]: LANG: en_GB.UTF-8 2019-03-09T21:34:42.167118+00:00 shinyapps[778397]: R
> version: 3.5.2 2019-03-09T21:34:42.167120+00:00 shinyapps[778397]:
> httpuv version: 1.4.5.1 2019-03-09T21:34:42.167119+00:00
> shinyapps[778397]: shiny version: 1.2.0
> 2019-03-09T21:34:42.167126+00:00 shinyapps[778397]: knitr version: NA
> 2019-03-09T21:34:42.167125+00:00 shinyapps[778397]: rmarkdown version:
> NA 2019-03-09T21:34:42.167466+00:00 shinyapps[778397]: Error in
> enforcePackage(name, curVersion) :  2019-03-09T21:34:42.167468+00:00
> shinyapps[778397]:   The rmarkdown package was not found in the
> library. 2019-03-09T21:34:42.167469+00:00 shinyapps[778397]: Calls:
> local ... eval -> eval -> eval -> <Anonymous> -> enforcePackage
> 2019-03-09T21:34:42.167131+00:00 shinyapps[778397]: jsonlite version:
> 1.6 2019-03-09T21:34:42.167137+00:00 shinyapps[778397]: RJSONIO version: NA 2019-03-09T21:34:42.167470+00:00 shinyapps[778397]:
> Execution halted 2019-03-09T21:34:42.167167+00:00 shinyapps[778397]:
> htmltools version: 0.3.6
> ```

This app used to work fine, but now for some reason `rmarkdown` package seems to be missing on the server and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: in shinyapps.io there is a clear package cache options. You could try doing that and try redeploying the file.

Comment: I have tried to deploy without package cache, it did not help

Comment: I had `packrat::on()` in my project, after `packrat::off()` everything seems to work fine.